# How to chain synchronous and aynchronous methods correctly together in CSharpFunctionalExtensions?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I am familiarizing with [CSharpFunctionalExtensions](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions). There are clear examples of [synchronous usage](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/blob/master/CSharpFunctionalExtensions.Examples/ResultExtensions/ExampleFromPluralsightCourse.cs#L9) and [asynchronous usage](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions/blob/master/CSharpFunctionalExtensions.Examples/ResultExtensions/AsyncUsageExamples.cs#L11). However, in some situations these needs to be chained together (sync and async combined). Am I doing this correctly by using `Task.FromResult` in my `Main` method? Or should I call a different functional extension method? For this situation, it works and the application outputs the expected **8** but that does not mean that this is the best approach I can use in all my software applications.

```
    class Program
    {
        // Assume this is a normal synchronous operation
        static Result<int> GetMyLength(string text) => Result.Ok(text.Length);

        // Assume this a typical async operation, such as a web request
        static async Task<Result<int>> DuplicateThisAsync(int x) => await Task.FromResult(Result.Ok(x * 2));

        static async Task Main()
        {
            var tryResult = await Task.FromResult(GetMyLength("Daan"))
                                .OnSuccess(a => DuplicateThisAsync(a));
            Console.WriteLine(tryResult.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to await on Synchronous operation

```
class Program
    {
        // Assume this is a normal synchronous operation
        static Result<int> GetMyLength(string text) => Result.Ok(text.Length);

        // Assume this a typical async operation, such as a web request
        static async Task<Result<int>> DuplicateThisAsync(int x) => await Task.FromResult(Result.Ok(x * 2));

        static async Task Main()
        {
            var tryResult = GetMyLength("Daan")
            if tryResult.Success // Something similar if .Success is not available
            {
               tryResult = await DuplicateThisAsync(tryResult.Value));
               Console.WriteLine(tryResult.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code does something fundamentally different. I want `DuplicateAsync` to be executed only `OnSuccess` of `GetMyLength`. That is why I want to chain them. You do not do this chaining.

Comment: awaiting synchronous operation is not recommending from performance perspective